# Difference between Preview and Production version of Azure AppFabric Access Control Service

Tags: azure, single-sign-on, appfabric, acs

I started to learn everything connected with Azure platform a little time ago. I'm really fascinated how some stuff works like a charm. One of that is AppFabric Access Control Service (ACS) and possibility of Single Sign On (SSO) with Facebook, Google, Live id...

When I was learning how to get running AppFabric I used preview version of it (available for free at https://portal.appfabriclabs.com/, but without SLA). Every tutorial about SSO was based on that Management portal.

Now, when I have my real Azure account (and AppFabric with it) I'm really confused because I can't find anywhere and section on portal where to configure ACS? I want to be able to create relaying party with facebook, live id and google identity provider using real appfabric account? Is that possible?

On some places I saw that this what I'm talking is only preview version of future ACS and that is not in production yet. So, if that is true, my main question is can I use production version (real appfabric account) to do single sign on on my web app? If not, what can I do with current production ACS version? What is the main purpose of it?

If someone have some links where are described main difference between Preview and Production version of AppFabric ACS, I will appreciate that.

P.S - Only tutorial that I found and is considered on current production release of ACS is at https://portal.appfabriclabs.com/. But I don't see integration with facebook, google.. There isn't SSO there...

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The current production version of ACS is a subset of what you see in the "Labs". Production currently supports SWT and WRAP. No WS-Federation, no WS-Trust, no (or limited) SAML.

All the cool stuff you mention (SSO for websites, out of the box integration with FB, Google, Yahoo! and LiveID, etc) is available on ACS "Labs" (which is not production yet).